# Django Database Filter in views page

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I created Django app for users monthly project report. I added users project data in Django admin portal with completed year,month and date. Now I need to display the data in views page according to the month and year or any specific  date which they are selecting in view page.

For example, if users want to see September 2018 month data, in data.html page users will select 2018 and September from drop down list and they will click generate button to get the report for that selected month and year. Below I attached screenshot link for data.html page.

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use Django queryset that filter the data saved in the database; to understand more read the documentations in this link:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#q

Example:

```
Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__lte='2018-09-01')
```

Or for more complex queries you can use the Q from django.models:

```
model.objects.get(Q(pub_date=date(2018, 5, 2)) | Q(pub_date=date(2016, 5, 6))
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the guidance. I got some idea in filter. And I filtered some what. But mainly what I want is I want to link that filter to my drop down. For example as you see in image if user selected 2018 in year and November in month it should display only corresponding data. So how to link that month filter to month drop down and year filter to year drop down? And after selecting two queries user will click on generate button to generate report. If possible please help me